# shaders' plugin installation in QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I want to try using [QML ShaderEffectItem on QGraphicsView](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2011/05/03/qml-shadereffectitem-on-qgraphicsview/)

I have cloned files from https://qt.gitorious.org/qt-labs/qml1-shadersplugin how is written in post, and i have compiled this plugin in `~/Dev/GitRepo/qml1-shadersplugin$`:

using QtCreator, compiles this file: `qmlshadersplugin.pro`

But now i run in this folder(~/Dev/GitRepo/qml1-shadersplugin): make install

And i have many: errors:

```
~/Dev/GitRepo/qml1-shadersplugin$ make installcd src/ && make -f Makefile install
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/goran/Dev/GitRepo/qml1-shadersplugin/src'
g++ -c -m32 -pipe -O2 -D_REENTRANT -Wall -W -fPIC -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_DECLARATIVE_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/linux-g++-32 -I. -I../../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/include/QtCore -I../../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/include/QtGui -I../../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/include/QtOpenGL -I../../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/include/QtDeclarative -I../../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I. -o qmlshadersplugin_plugin.o qmlshadersplugin_plugin.cpp
In file included from ../../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/include/QtOpenGL/QtOpenGL:5:0,
                 from shadereffectitem.h:46,
                 from qmlshadersplugin_plugin.cpp:43:
../../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/include/QtOpenGL/qgl.h:77:20: fatal error: GL/gl.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [qmlshadersplugin_plugin.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/igor/Dev/GitRepo/qml1-shadersplugin/src'
make: *** [sub-src-install_subtargets] Error 2
```

What's the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GL/gl.h: No such file or directory
```

This means that you either do not have opengl library installed (very unlikely), or you didn't enabled it in your qmake file (very likely). To enable opengl in the qmake file, you need to add this line :

```
QT += opengl
```

More about it [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qmake-variable-reference.html#qt).

Comment: or, to me most likely, the opengl development packages are missing, libmesa-dev or something along those lines.